# Embedding of fields in central simple algebras over number fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $K$ be a non-real CM number field of degree $2d$, with maximal totally real subfield $K_0$, and let $A$ be a central simple algebra over $K$, so that $A\simeq M_n(E)$, the $n\times n$ matrix ring over a certain central division ring $E$ over $K$. Let $s$ denote the index of $E$, i.e., $[E:K]=s^2$.

Here is my question: suppose that $F\subset A$ is a totally real number field of degree $nsd$ which is embedded in $A$. Is it then true that $F$ is forced to intersect the center $K$ of $A$ in $K_0$?

One can show that the compositum $FK$ inside $A$ has degree $ns2d$, it being a maximal commutative semi-simple subalgebra of $A$. This does not quite show, however, that $K$ over $F\cap K$ has degree 2..

Any help, hints, or indication of references would be appreciated. Thanks.

PS: The question came up when looking at endomorphism rings of reductions at finite places of abelian varieties over number fields with real multiplication by a totally real number field.

Comment: Yes. If the central $K_0$ weren't contained in $F$ then $FK_0$ would be a strictly larger commutative semisimple subalgebra, so its $F$-degree is at least 2 and hence its $\mathbf{Q}$-degree is at least $ns(2d)$, so it is forced to be a maximal commutative semisimple subalgebra of $A$.  That forces it to contain the center $K$, but this is impossible since $K$ has no real embedding and $FK_0$ is a direct product of totally real fields (as $F$ and $K$ are totally real).  So indeed $K_0 \subset F$ inside $A$.  But clearly $K \not\subset F$ inside $A$, so $F \cap K = K_0$ inside $A$.